# Is the length of a rectifiable complex curve strictly increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory

Most of this notation is from *Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis*:

Let $\gamma$ be the parameterized curve in the complex plane given by $z(t) = \left(x(t),y(t) \right)$, where $a \leq t \leq b$.

Suppose that $\gamma$ is rectifiable, so that its length is finite on $[a,b]$.

I am not too comfortable visualizing complex-valued functions. My question is, if $L(a,t)$ is the length of $\gamma$ on $[a,t]$, is $L(a,t)$ strictly increasing?

This may be an obvious question (if so, great!), but I want to make sure. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $\gamma$ to be *locally non-constant* (not a standard term?) on $[a, b]$ if, for every interval $[c, d] \subset [a, b]$, the curve $\gamma$ is not constant on $[c, d]$. (For example, if $\gamma$ is of class $C^{1}$ and $\gamma'$ does not vanish on any interval, then $\gamma$ is locally non-constant.)

If $\gamma$ is locally non-constant, then arc length along $\gamma$ is strictly increasing: If $a \leq c < d \leq b$, then by hypothesis there exists a number $s$ with $c < s < d$ such that $\gamma(c) \neq \gamma(s)$. Consequently,
\begin{align*}
L(a, c)
  &< L(a, c) + \|\gamma(c) - \gamma(s)\| \\
  &\leq L(a, c) + L(c, s) \\
  &= L(a, s) \\
  &\leq L(a, d).
\end{align*}

Inversely, if $\gamma$ *is* constant on some interval, the arc length function obviously fails to be strictly increasing.

Comment: Great answer! One question: If I know that $z(t)$ is injective, is this sufficient to say that $\gamma$ is locally non constant?

Comment: Yes. :) In fact, if $\gamma$ is injective the proof is easier: If $s < t$, then$$L(a, s) < L(a, s) + \|\gamma(t) - \gamma(s)\| \leq L(a, t).$$

Comment: Excellent, thank you!